# Kentico not creating anonymous contact records

Tags: kentico, kentico-13

I have enabled Kentico Activity Tracking for contacts. However, Kentico does not create any anonymous contact records of the public site visitors. It only create a contact record if the user submits a form. How do I enable activity tracking of any user who visits the site. Regardless of form submissions?

Here are a few screenshots of my settings in Kentico admin

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, Kentico has created contacts only for users who have submitted a form with an email address but no public site visitor contact records have been created.

Note: I haven't really added the geolocation maxmind DB. Not sure if this is required to log public user activities.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see it has created 2 anonymous contacts.  Keep in mind if you're the one testing all the time, you should clear the contact guid cookie from your browser session so the system thinks you're a new contact visiting the site. To get different contacts to be created, try different devices on different networks and you'll see the new contacts be created.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, Activity Tracking needs CookieLevel 1000.

https://docs.xperience.io/on-line-marketing-features/configuring-and-customizing-your-on-line-marketing-features/configuring-activities/enabling-activity-tracking